# Fine Uploader (S3 version) throwing JS error of some IE8 browsers

Tags: fine-uploader

I can't reproduce this, but a bunch of the users are having this problem.  They are all on IE8.  The problem is in the ajax request to get the signature before submitting to S3.  The signature url is on the same domain.

Here is the log:

```
LOG: [FineUploader 3.8.0] Received 1 files or inputs.
LOG: [FineUploader 3.8.0] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
  Object expected  s3.jquery.fineuploader.js, line 3735 character 17
```

Line 3735 corresponds to (in function getXhrOrXdr):

```
xhrOrXdr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Here is the browser user-agent:

```
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2)
```

Is this some browser setting or firewall/security thing?  I have other ajax parts of the site that work fine using jQuery.

Comment: I figured out how to reproduce.  If you turn off "Enable native XMLHTTP support" in Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security it will produce the error.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to mention that in the answer I'm typing up now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All versions of IE, starting with IE7, allow you to turn off/disable `XMLHttpRequest`.  Fine Uploader depends on `XMLHttpRequest` to send signature requests to your server.  If your customers have XHR disabled, they will need to re-enable it.

Comment: Any chance that Fine Uploader will implement the workaround to use the ActiveXObject?  I assume that is what jQuery is doing since they seems to be able to run ajax requests on the same browser.

Comment: Possibly.  Please open up a feature request so we can discuss potentially adding it to the schedule.

Comment: @user1152220 It looks like we will likely make this a high-priority addition to Fine Uploader and release the addition as a 3.8.2 hotfix.

Comment: We just released 3.8.2 which includes an ActiveX fallback and a fix for the special characters issue in IE9 and older.